# How to get time of methods in c++?

Tags: c++

So I'd like to measure running time for my  4  Methods in my programm, but i don't know how and where to place timer. I've tried to use chrono library, but i think i've used it wrongly.

```
class Funkcje_matematyczne
{
    public:
        unsigned long long n;
        int b,p;
        void Metoda_Naiwna1(unsigned long long n);
        void Metoda_Naiwna2(unsigned long long n);
        void Odwrocone_tw_wilsona(unsigned long long n);
        int Odwrocone_mal_tw_Fermata(int b,int p);
};
int main()
{
    Funkcje_matematyczne a;
    unsigned long long n;
    int b,p;

    cin >> n;

    a.Metoda_Naiwna1(n);
    a.Metoda_Naiwna2(n);
    a.Odwrocone_tw_wilsona(n);

    cout << "Podaj dwie liczby do tw Fermata"<<endl;
    cin >> b >> p;
    a.Odwrocone_mal_tw_Fermata(b,p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *I've tried to use chrono library* You should show you attempt in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Using chrono library it can be as easy as:

```
auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
funcUnderTest();
auto duration = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - start;
```

PS: If you need better precision you can also use `std::chrono:high_resolution_clock`, but depending from platfrom it can be same as `std::chrono::steady_clock`.

Comment: what is the standard unit for chrono? miliseconds nanoseconds?

Comment: There is no "standard unit" you need to cast it to type you need. I.e. if you want milliseconds you can do `auto milli = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(duration).count();` PS: Resolution of clocks is platform specific and is not defined by C++.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `QElapsedTimer` for that

```cpp
QList<qint64> measurements;
QElapsedTimer timer;

timer.start();
a.Metoda_Naiwna1(n);
measurements.append(timer.restart());

a.Metoda_Naiwna2(n);
measurements.append(timer.restart());

a.Odwrocone_tw_wilsona(n);
measurements.append(timer.restart());

cout << "Podaj dwie liczby do tw Fermata"<<endl;
cin >> b >> p;

timer.restart();
a.Odwrocone_mal_tw_Fermata(b,p);
measurements.append(timer.restart());

qDebug() 
        << "Metoda_Naiwna1" << measurements[0]
        << "Metoda_Naiwna2" << measurements[1]
        << "Odwrocone_tw_wilsona" << measurements[2]
        << "Odwrocone_mal_tw_Fermata" << measurements[3];
```

Comment: it returns me 0.00000 for all the methods, it also was like that when i used chrono library

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I've been using `std::chrono`...

```
class Timer
{
    const char* m_Name;
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point m_Start;
public:
    Timer(const char* name) :
        m_Name( name ),
        m_Start( std::chrono::steady_clock::now() )
    {}

    ~Timer()
    {
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        int us = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>( end - m_Start ).count();
        float ms = us/1000;
        std::cout << "Timer(" << m_Name << "):" << ms <<"\n";
    }
};
```

This can be used as follows...

```
{
    Timer("Naiwna1");
    a.Metoda_Naiwna1(n);
}
{
    Timer("Naiwna2");
    a.Metoda_Naiwna2(n);
}
```

The `Timer` measures and prints the elapsed time from its creation to its destruction, defined by the curly braces around it.